# Getting Open Graph og:image for page without being a page administrator

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, case-sensitive

I want to use open graph to query the og:image and og:description value for a web page for which I am not an administrator.

I've tried using open graph and fql with both the id of the page and the url, but neither return that information.

I figured that since both values were "public" (they can be viewed in the source of the page) that they would also be public in OpenGraph.

Short of parsing the page myself, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took http://www.southparkstudios.com/ and checked the data returned by the [Facebook Object Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.southparkstudios.com/) and varified it had the description and image properties, then I simply clicked the [Graph API url](http://graph.facebook.com/388598437807) of the object (at the bottom of the page, *Urls* section) and received the site data, and it contained the image and description properties.

Based on that check, if you have the id of the web page then it should give you that info using the graph api, all you need is an active access token, even an application token will probably do the trick.

What did you get when you queried for that data? Did you get an error? just a smaller subset of the data?
Also, can you show the code of how you tried to get that data, both graph api and fql.

Comment: What I discovered is that the open graph API is case sensitive and "picky".  You will get different data if you omit the trailing slash.  In my case, the page was "/Home.aspx, and I was searching /home.aspx.  Thanks for the clues.

Comment: Oh yeah, of course, facebook uses the urls to index web pages, every character counts. Even _/Home.aspx?id=34_ will index differently than _/Home.aspx?id=87_. As for case sensitive, that's usually the case.

Comment: I get that your case should resolve to different OG objects, but the case of /Home.aspx vs. /home.aspx shouldn't, IMHO.  Url's aren't case sensitive, so the OG API shouldn't be, either.

Comment: I retract that last comment!  http://www.wisegeek.com/are-urls-case-sensitive.htm